# detecting IE with jquery and redirect does not work on shipedia.eu

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am working on a site Joomla component. You can see it at [www.shipedia.eu](http://www.shipedia.eu) on the startpage. It is a searchmask for cruises.

Now my problem:

I have a "Suchen & Finden" Button on the start page, it should start a AJAX query (performed with jQuery). With the answer of the ajax query I want to change the content of the page. In the FF and all good browsers it works fine, but not in IE ... So what I have done to fix that is to check if the user is using the IE. If he is using the IE it should not perform the ajax-query but redirect with window.location(). It works magically on the IE installed on one of my windows pc but really just there, on every other windows pc I have tried it doesn't work.

Here the code which I used to identify the IE and perform the redirect:

```
// check for ie
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            window.location(url);
        }
```

What I need is to identify the IE and to redirect to a given URL or to perform a AJAX query and change the content.

EDIT:

Here the whole code that I am using to start the ajax-query or to do the redirect:

```
    // button link
    jQuery('.button_s_link').click(function(){

        // wait on
        jQuery('#wait').show();

        // sammle die werte
        var toc =           jQuery('.change_toc:checked').val();
        var zielgebiet =    jQuery('.zielgebiete_s_select').val();
        var from =          jQuery('.from').val();
        var to =            jQuery('.to').val();
        var reederei =      jQuery('.reederei_s_select').val();
        var schiff =        jQuery('.schiff_s_select').val();

        // erstelle url
        var url =   'index.php'
                   +'?option=com_kreuzfahrten'
                   +'&view=filter'
                   +'&search=1'
                   +'&toc='+toc
                   +'&zielgebiet='+zielgebiet
                   +'&from='+from
                   +'&to='+to
                   +'&reederei='+reederei
                   +'&schiff='+schiff;

        // check for ie
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            url += '&Itemid=<?php echo JRequest::getVar('Itemid'); ?>';
            window.location(url);
        } else {
            url += '&format=raw'
                +  '&template=raw_filter';
        }

        // lade filter ansicht
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('.mainContainer_s').empty().html(function(){
                  // wait off
                  jQuery('#wait').hide();
                  return data;
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alertErrorMsg();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 window.location = url;
 //window.location is not a function
```

Comment: Its all good mang. Are you still having a problem? Or did that clear it up?